# Samba4 (active directory) managed service account

Tags: active-directory, samba

I currently run a Samba4 domain controller which is emulating Windows 2008 R2 however when I check AD from the tools (AD users and computers) I am unable to add a Managed Service Account.

The user I am trying to create is not for a real person but for a service to use LDAP to do user lookups. Is there a way I can manually extend the schema to support Managed Service Accounts or will Samba4 not support this type of feature?

This Folder/CN does not exist:

[image: MSA]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear like this is a supported feature in Samba yet. It doesn't create the needed container, nor does it actually support the [well known object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223663.aspx) associated with it.

I would also suspect that there are other missing things in Samba that would make this work, as it essentially provides automatic password management of the account. I cannot find anything in the Samba source that would suggest it supports something like this.

Comment: Pity really. I thought I could get away from Microsoft CALs using an AD replacement. Samba AD DC seems quite reliable but does not look to be feature complete when compared to Windows 2008 R2 which it tries to emulate.

Comment: MSA account passwords are rotated by the client, not by the DC, just like a computer account. So in that regard, I don't think the Samba DC needs any code to handle an MSA. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/